# 3D rolling link with different content

Tags: javascript, css, html, effects

Is it possible to realize a 3D rolling link [(click for example)](http://zsitro.com/css3-rolling-links/) with a different content when rolling? So let's say there is a DIV, and when the user `hover` over the DIV, the DIV spins (like in the example) and shows another DIV with another (**clickable** and with different action) content? Do you think this is possible just in CSS, or is there JS needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, see here an example: [demo rotating cube](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/cube-02-show-sides.html)

and here you can find a description [description](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/cube.html)

Answer (score 1):

The example you gave allows it.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhVqA/)

You just have to change the data-title in the HTML...

```
<div id="reveal">
<a href="http://zsitro.com/" class=" roll">
    <span data-title="****CHANGE-ME****">H5BP build script</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. but am i able with your way to add several **clickable** (different actions) divs on rolling? because that is what i want to do